# conditional insert on previous rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `players` table with the following definition:

```
   Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |               Default
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------
 id          | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('players_id_seq'::regclass)
 player_name | character varying(64)       |           | not null |
 server_name | character varying(64)       |           | not null |
 joined_at   | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
```

It has data such as:

```
 id | player_name | server_name  |         joined_at
----+-------------+--------------+----------------------------
  1 | Jane        | blue-server  | 2021-04-27 10:42:51.986282
  2 | Matt        | red-server   | 2021-04-27 10:42:51.986282
  3 | Jane        | green-server | 2021-04-27 10:42:51.986282
  4 | Jane        | blue-server  | 2021-04-27 10:42:51.986282
```

I have created a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vDkGMgsCiv1dqS7P2WpBTt/0).

**Desired Query**

I want to write an `insert` whose success depends on the `player_name` and `server_name` values. If the last inserted row for the given `player_name` and `server_name` combination matches, then the insert should fail, otherwise, the insert should go ahead.

So in the above, the following insert **should fail**:

```
insert into players (player_name, server_name, joined_at) values ('Matt', 'red-server', now());
```

Because the last record for `player_name = 'Matt'` also had the same `server_name = 'red-server'`

However, both of these should **succeed**:

```
insert into players (player_name, server_name, joined_at) values ('Matt', 'grey-server', now());
insert into players (player_name, server_name, joined_at) values ('Matt', 'red-server', now());
```

I hope that makes sense. Here's another example. The below **should fail**:

```
insert into players (player_name, server_name, joined_at) values ('Jane', 'blue-server', now());
```

I'm not sure how to go about achieving this in SQL.

Comment: Last by id or joined_at?

Comment: I think either one works here. Let's say `joined_at`

Comment: If you want the DB to enforce this, rather than your application, you likely need to use a trigger to enforce the constraint.  Just be very careful regarding insertion of multiple rows at the same time *(Such as your rows for Jane, all being at the exact same timestamp, so likely being inserted together, none of those three rows come "first" in time order)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CTE that returns the column values that you want to insert and use `INSERT ... SELECT` from the CTE with a `WHERE` clause instead of `INSERT ... VALUES`:

```
WITH cte(player_name, server_name, joined_at) AS (SELECT 'Matt', 'red-server', now())
INSERT INTO players (player_name, server_name, joined_at) 
SELECT c.*
FROM cte c
WHERE c.server_name <> 
      COALESCE((SELECT p.server_name FROM players p WHERE p.player_name = c.player_name ORDER BY joined_at DESC LIMIT 1), '')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=eba9af46d721a4c8a37e8520988de399).